# Bitbucket repo is over the 2 GB limit issue

Tags: git, bitbucket

I create Bitbucket repo and pushed there 2.5 Gb.  (I then deleted from local pc)

Then I found that Bitbucket has limit of 2 Gb for repo.  I decided to split 2.5 in smaller subprojects but found that I cannot even load sources from Bitbucket.  When I do `git clone remote-url` or `git clone --depth 1 remote-url`

> This repo is over the 2 GB limit and is in read-only mode. Read more
>   on how to reduce the size of your repository.

or

> remote: abort: repository is in read only mode (over 2 GB size limit).
>   fatal: unable to access 'https://zzz@bitbucket.org/zzz/projects.git/':
>   The requested URL returned error: 503

Is there solution to just load my repo from bitbucket?

Comment: have you considered contacting attlassian?

Answer (score -1):

I think the best thing to do is contacting Technical Support. They should guide you much better than what we can.

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24518142/641451) they recommend it, too.