# Clear bitbucket cache

Tags: git, bitbucket

Is there any way to clear bitbucket's repo history cache?

Background: I used

```
git filter-branch --force --index-filter \
'git rm --cached --ignore-unmatch PATH-TO-YOUR-FILE-WITH-SENSITIVE-DATA' \
--prune-empty --tag-name-filter cat -- --all
```

to delete the `FILE-WITH-SENSITIVE-DATA` and clean the commits history. This worked smoothly. The file is no longer in commit.

But now, knowing the commit's hash I still can view the original commit in browser (which has the file's contents). Assumption is that is stored in bitbucket server's cache.

Any way I can make sure that even this cache is cleaned?

Comment: Perhaps it's in *your* cache?

Comment: @Amit nice call! But, unfortunately, it's not a browser issue - checked

Comment: I think you'll have to contact Bitbucket support and ask them to run `git gc` for you. [This answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/27868384/354577) suggests that they'll be willing to do so. In any case, you should probably invalidate the exposed data if at all possible (e.g. change password, generate new app keys, etc.)

Comment: @Chris thanks man! Already contacted them - waiting for the action)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Contacting Bitbucket support asking them to run

```
git gc
```

resolved the issue.

Comment: Can you please provide me the section of the contact? I am having trouble of finding the right section to ask. It always takes me to purchasing licenses..