# remote: This repository is currently 1.1 GB in size. If it exceeds 2 GB it will be put into read-only mode

Tags: git, bitbucket

When I ran git push I got this

```
⚡️  js  git push
Enumerating objects: 9, done.
Counting objects: 100% (9/9), done.
Delta compression using up to 8 threads
Compressing objects: 100% (5/5), done.
Writing objects: 100% (5/5), 485 bytes | 485.00 KiB/s, done.
Total 5 (delta 3), reused 0 (delta 0)
```

> remote: This repository is currently 1.1 GB in size. If it exceeds 2 GB it will be put into read-only mode.

```
remote: Learn how to reduce your repository size: https://confluence.atlassian.com/x/xgMvEw
To bitbucket.org:user/reponame.git
   73012de..c96b1fd  master -> master
```

When I clone down my repo, and check size. It's only

[image]

---

When I ran

rm -rf `.git` and push to new **repo**

[image]

What is going on here?

What did I missed ?

Comment: Ever tried importing these 186.2 MB into a new remote repository?

Comment: Might be something to do with a fork? Has the repo you’re cloning been forked?

Comment: you could compare these repositories with [git-sizer](https://github.com/github/git-sizer/).

Answer (score 1):

It could be a repository where `git gc` was *not* run from a long time.

Start by creating, then deleting a branch directly on the BitBucket site (*not* locally): that should trigger a `git gc` on BitBucket.
See then if the warning persists.

If not, try a `reflog expire + prune --expire + git gc --aggressive`, followed by a `push -f`, as done in "[How to cleanup garbage in remote git repo](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37253227/6309)", to see if that helps.